# How to Access QSettings() of QGIS from outside QGIS Console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5

How can we access all the keys under QSettings() of QGIS 3.4 and above? Requirement is such that we need to set some QSettings() keys for smooth working of developed Plugins from outside of QGIS.

But I am not able to access the keys . If I run following lines in the Python Console (the one that comes with QGIS, inside QGIS/apps/Python37/Python.exe)

```
settings=QSettings()

settings.allKeys()
```

It results in an empty list. However same 2 lines if we run from QGIS Python Console it gives out all the Key Groups under which settings are stored.

How to access those Key Groups and how to modify them from outside of QGIS Environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within QGIS Python console, get the `ini` file path from `QSettings`

```
settings = QSettings()
print(settings.fileName())
```

Then in your Python console, use path from above `settings.fileName()` like below

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings

settings = QSettings('/your/ini/path/ini', QSettings.IniFormat)
# Now working
print(settings.allKeys())
```

Comment: Thankyou very much ThomasG77.